# How to check if LastParagraph exists in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdf, paragraph, migradoc

I need to check is the sections has a LastParagraph, but comparing it to `null` doesn't work and I don't seem to find any relevant method that would help me to check if LastParagraph.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I've tried:

```
var paragraph = sec.LastParagraph == null ? sec.AddParagraph() : sec.LastParagraph;
```

and

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
if (sec.LastParagraph == null)
    paragraph = sec.AddParagraph();
else
    paragraph = sec.LastParagraph;
```

and also:

```
Paragraph paragraph = sec.LastParagraph;
if(paragraph == null)
    paragraph = sec.AddParagraph();
```

All throw a `System.NullReferenceException`

According to the intelisense this should return null if it doesn't exist
[image: intelisense print]

I really didn't want to wrap this code in a `try catch block`, but is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the exception occurs only when you call `LastParagraph` without ever calling any `AddXxx` methods for that section.

There is a potential bug in MigraDoc and invoking something like `var dummy = sec.Elements.Count;` before calling `LastParagraph` should avoid the exception until this bug is fixed with a forthcoming version of MigraDoc.

I didn't try running this workaround, this is just a guess after checking the source code. Please let me know if the workaround helps.

Comment: I ended up using the sec.Elemets.Count anyways since if it is 0 I know that LastParagraph is null, thanks for the tip.

Comment: And BTW, What you said stands correct, after I add the `var dummy = sec.Elements.Count;` Line, the sec.LastParagraph stoped throwing the exception.